# the role of AIC versus p-values in model selection

Tags: model-selection, aic

Let's say you are trying to choose between two models. One has two significant fixed effects. The other includes only one of the two fixed effects from the aforementioned model but has a lower AIC (and the fixed effect is still significant). Which model should I choose?

Comment: So the latter is nested w/i the former? I'm not sure I see how that is possible. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your analyses? Can you paste in your output?

Comment: Yes, the latter is nested within the former. I'm using the software MixCat and the output is rather large. What specifically do you want to see? I am running a nonproportional odds ordinal generalized linear mixed model. I am looking at contests in spiders. The fixed effects in the first model are 1) the size of a spider's opponent and 2) the difference in size between the spider and his opponent. The fixed effect in the second model is the difference in size between the spider and his opponent. The dependent variable is contest escalation.

Comment: sorry, I meant to write the software SuperMix, not MixCat. Getting all these mixed names mixed up..

Comment: Firstly, you should probably use AICc, not pure AIC. That being said, it sounds as if that the information criterion is telling you that the additional effect does not help the likelihood as much as the additional parameter penalizes it. In other words, the additional variable isn't worth the parameter risk.

Comment: Thanks very much, that answers my question! I had heard of AICc but hadn't paid much attention to it until you directed my attention to it. Thanks again!